# Removing the help icon from the homepage header servicenow

Tags: servicenow

I just started with servicenow. 
I am looking for the way to modify the header and hide the help icon, only for the homepage. Any suggestion or useful articles - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> This Toggle Help Sidebar is added by a embedded help plugin.
>   In order to hide it , you need to traverse through the sys_properties.list << com.glide.embedded_help.enabled << Set Value as false.
>   logout and login back again with the new user session.

https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=d0ac07e5db9cdbc01dcaf3231f96195c

If you want to hide it for a single page you can write a global UI script and hide the DOM element if the URL is the right one.